# May someone help me figure out how to update my dashes on my python hangman code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am supposed to be able to update these dashes so that when someone types in "a" the dashes will look like a---a-. And if the user guesses the letter "l", the dashes will look like a---al.

```
magic_word = "animal"  

dashes = "--------"   

def get_guess()   

while True:  
print dashes  
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter: "))  
 if len(guess)>1:    
        print "Too long"     
        continue    
 elif not guess.islower():  
        print "Your guess must be one lowercase letter"  
        continue  
    if guess in magic_word :  
        print "That is in the word"  
        continue  
    else:  
        print "That is not in the word"  
        continue  
        return guess  
        break  
get_guess()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use a different method to see if the guess is in the magic word.

One such method would be to iterate through the string and whenever the guess is found in the magic word, update the corresponding space in the dashes string:

```
for x in range(len(magic_word)):
    if guess == magic_word[x]:
        dashes[x] = guess
```

Which would update the dashes for you

Comment: On this assignment, I am supposed to use the "while True" loop, so would I replace that with "for x in range..."

Comment: You would put it under the 

     "if guess in magic_word : " 

statement

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "index()" method for finding the index of the character and then by using the "replace()" method for replacing the dashes with that word.

```
indexOfGuessChar = magic_word.index(guess)
dashes = dashes.replace(dashes[indexOfGuessChar], guess)
```

something like this will do the trick just put these functions to work and play with it.